# First Data Curl WSDL SSL Failure

Tags: php, soap, ssl, curl, firstdata

I am integrating with FirstData wsdl. following the [`First Data Global Gateway
Web Service API
Integration Guide`](http://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CF8QFjAA&url=http://www.firstdata.com/downloads/marketing-merchant/fdgg-web-service-api.pdf&ei=XOa8T6FSh86tB6qN8cAN&usg=AFQjCNFukMvmj3nb_n7EtIlzkQ5vWzQiYw&sig2=QBhGHRPN4P7owq6BhX0UrQ)
. `$kslocation` is path to `.key` file. `$kslocation` is the path to `.pem` file and all these paths are valid.

```
$ch = curl_init($wsdl);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: text/xml"));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$userid:$password");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $body);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLCERT, $pemlocation);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLKEY, $kslocation);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLKEYPASSWD, $keyname);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
echo curl_error($ch)."\n";
curl_close($ch);
```

is giving me error.

```
SSL read: error:1409441B:SSL routines:SSL3_READ_BYTES:tlsv1
alert decrypt error, errno 0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was I was using the test account url. I changed it to the live url and it worked.